# Exercise in probability

Tags: probability

Security Guards of an industrial plant are trained to contact office over the 'special Frequency Radio set' in case of emergency. However , emergency seldom arises and radio sets are not maintained on regular basis. This result in the communication failure due to failure of the radio sets when needed. the past data indicates that probability of such failure is 15%. Company has an option of installing more number of radio sets to ensure that at least one would work properly when needed. what is the minimum number of radio sets company should install to keep the risk of communication failure below 1%?

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

The company decides to install $n$ radio sets , and according to the past data, the probability of failure for each of them is $p=15\%$ . We can assume that each radio set fails independently of the others. Let $A_k$ denotes the failure of the $k^{th}$ radio set.

The probability that all of them fails is $$P(\cap_{k=1}^nA_k)$$.

By mutual independence , we have 
$$P(\cap_{k=1}^nA_k)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}P(A_k)$$.

Each of them have a probability of failure, thus 
$$P(\cap_{k=1}^nA_k)=p^n$$

We want this probability to be lower than $1\%$, therefore , we must solve 
$$p^n<1\%$$
or
$$nln(p)<ln(0.01)$$

Finally,given that $ln(p)=ln(0.15)<0$, $n$ must be greater  than $\frac{ln(0.01)}{ln(0.15)}\approx 2.43$. One must choose $n=3$.